# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away creating temporary table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Everything I've seen is due to plugins or "weird" configurations or data sets.

I'm trying to do something very simple with PHP, MySQL, and PDO.

```
    $table_name = 'TEMP_' . time();
    $sql_commands = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE {$table_name} (X CHAR(1));";
    $conn = Database::factory();
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql_commands);
    $stmt->execute();
```

Database::factory() is essential returning a PDO object created from:

```
$opt = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET time_zone = '" . TIME_ZONE . "';",
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 10485760;",
];

$dsn = "mysql:dbname=$database;host=$hostname;port=$port;charset=utf8";
```

Every time I try to create temporary tables I get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away
```

However the table does get created (At least, if I rerun too quick I get another error stating the table already exists.)

Contents of /etc/my.cnf

```
max_allowed_packet=128MB  # tried various values from 8MB up to 4GB
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
secure_file_priv=""
symbolic-links=0
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES 

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

For brevity of this post [SHOW VARIABLES DUMP](https://pastebin.com/BpT40wUJ) is pastebin'd.

Answer (score 0):

Should your PREPARE and EXECUTE be followed by CLOSE to complete typical cycle?

max_allowed_packet=128MB  should be 
max_allowed_packet=128M    in your cnf

please post your error log into the question.

Comment: Appreciate the effort but in the end I started shelling to mysql cli client.  Not elegant by any means but as it's a cron job it's sufficient. Thank You

Comment: Well, if you do not get CLOSE added to your logic after PREPARE and EXECUTE's,  resources will not be released at the end of your session.

max_allowed_packet is 1GB from what I see in your variables.  Maybe you need it for processing LOAD INPUT operations.
Enjoy